# Visual Studio Team Services ASPNET CORE build failure

Tags: azure-devops, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm trying to setup a build definition for a new ASPNET Core webapp.

The setup of the build definition is exactly this:
[Official Docs](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/apps/aspnet/aspnetcore-to-azure)

The build fails at building the solution with this error:

```
Issues
Build 

File name doesn't indicate a full path to a executable file.

GETSDKTOOLINGINFO (0, 0) 
The project is configured to use .NET Core SDK version 1.0.0-preview2-003131 which is not installed or cannot be found under the path C:\Program Files\dotnet. These components are required to build and run this project. Download the version of .NET Core SDK specified in global.json or update the SDK version in global.json to the version that is installed.

Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
```

Any guess on how to solve this?
Thanks
Francesco

Comment: Do you solve this issue with my solution?

Comment: You can mark it as answer if one of our solution solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the corresponding version of .Net SDK to build agent machine.

You can refer to [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/blob/master/known-issues-vs2015.md) article to download .Net Core 1.0.0-preview2-003131 and install it on your build machine.

Comment: @CiaranBruen Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using hosted build agent. According to [Software on the hosted build server](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/hosted-pool#software-on-the-hosted-build-server), the hosted build server is deployed with the following .NET Framework:

- .NET 4.6
- .NET 4.5.2
- .NET 4.5.1
- .NET 4.5
- .NET 3.5 SP1
- .NET Core 1.0 with Preview 2 Tooling

You may try to deploy an on-premises build agent and install [.NET Core 1.0.1 SDK 1.0.0-preview2-003131](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/blob/master/known-issues.md#net-core-101-sdk-100-preview2-003131-download-links) to work with VSTS: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/index#deploy_agent.

If you insist on using hosted build agent, then you need to use version of Microsoft.NETCore.App that is installed in VSTS, for example:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
        "type": "platform"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was just a change in global.config:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003121"
  }
}
```

As long as `1.0.0-preview2-003131` is not available on VSO build hosts